# Java program termination in Windows vs Linux console (Ctrl-C not working under windows)

Tags: java, terminal

I wrote simple console Java program. It uses `ExecutorService` and it runs few threads.

I'm using it under Windows and Linux.

I can terminate it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> under Linux, but it doesn't work under Windows.

Can I "fix" this somehow in my program? (without changes in OS configuration or Java Runtime configuration).

I'm using JDK 1.8 / JRE 1.8. My code (with removed "work" part):

```
public class FileProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // run 5 threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        int i;

        // get first and last file ID to process
        int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int end = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        for (i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            final int finalId = i; // final necessary in anonymous class
            executor.submit(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    processFile(finalId);
                }
            });
        }

        // I put System.exit(0); here - program will end but threads will still work?
    }

    public static void processFile(int id)
    {
        //doing work here
    }
}
```

Comment: A snippet of problematic code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

In your Java program:

1. Terminate first your ExecutorService by calling shutdownNow() on it.
2. Then just before the ending brace ("}") of your program's main() method call System.exit(0);

Comment: But where should call executor.shutdownNow()? If work is being processed in seaparate threads they will shutdown I guess...